# How to apply image orientation to a CIImage?

Tags: swift, cifilter

I try to compose 2 images using a CIFilter but I cannot handle the image orientation properly.

I the following example, I've captured the same scene but with 2 different orientations of the phone (volume buttons on the top for the first image, on the bottom for the second image). On the following screenshot, the first image is displayed on the top and the second one in the middle. I verified that the 2 image orientations are different (cf `print` call).

SwiftUI handles the image orientation properly. If I now compose the 2 images using a CIFilter (third image), the orientation of the images is not taken into account and the compositing is not what I want (I want to have 2 mugs side by side).

This is obviously not bug. But how to rotate the input images based on their respective orientation before applying the compositing CIFIlter? What is the standard way of doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Here is the code corresponding to this simple example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var input1 = UIImage(named: "image1.jpg")
    @State var input2 = UIImage(named: "image2.jpg")
    @State var output : UIImage?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Image(uiImage: input1!)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()

            Image(uiImage: input2!)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()

            if output != nil {
                Image(uiImage: output!)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }

        }
        .onAppear(){
            self.compose()
        }
    }

    func compose() {

        print("Orientation of input1: \(input1!.imageOrientation.rawValue)")
        print("Orientation of input2: \(input2!.imageOrientation.rawValue)")

        let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)

        let ciInput1 = CIImage(image: input1!)
        let ciInput2 = CIImage(image: input2!)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CILinearDodgeBlendMode")!
        filter.setValue(ciInput1, forKey: "inputImage")
        filter.setValue(ciInput2, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage")

        let ciOutput = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage

        let cgOutput = ciContext.createCGImage(ciOutput, from: ciOutput.extent)!

        output = UIImage(cgImage: cgOutput)
    }
}
```

And here is the corresponding screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can tell Core Image to take the image's orientation into account when loading:

```
let ciInput1 = CIImage(image: input1!, options: [.applyOrientationProperty: true])
let ciInput2 = CIImage(image: input2!, options: [.applyOrientationProperty: true])
```

**Edit:**

So it seems the above only works when loading the image from URL or from data, not from `UIImage`.

You can apply the orientation yourself, however. Here's a handy extension:

```
extension UIImage.Orientation {
    var exifOrientation: Int32 {
        switch self {
            case .up: return 1
            case .down: return 3
            case .left: return 8
            case .right: return 6
            case .upMirrored: return 2
            case .downMirrored: return 4
            case .leftMirrored: return 5
            case .rightMirrored: return 7
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can transform the image like this:

```
let ciInput1 = CIImage(image: input1!).oriented(forExifOrientation: image1.imageOrientation.exifOrientation)
let ciInput2 = CIImage(image: input2!).oriented(forExifOrientation: image2.imageOrientation.exifOrientation)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I might have done something wrong as I see no change in the results.

Comment: Hmm... Can you please check what orientations are written in the metadata of the images?

Comment: Using XCode : `orientation 1=0, orientation 2=1`, using Preview (macOS) : `orientation1=1, orientation 2=3`.